# SSL certificates and keys in twisted python - missing private key client side?

Tags: python, authentication, ssl, certificate, twisted

I have the following python code as a server TLS server:

```
from twisted.internet import ssl, protocol, defer, task, endpoints
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.python.modules import getModule

class TLSServer(LineReceiver):
    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print("received: " + line)
        if line == "STARTTLS":
            print("-- Switching to TLS")
            self.sendLine('READY')
            self.sendLine('STARTTLS')
            self.transport.startTLS(self.factory.options)
            self.sendLine('Go ahead, secure now')
        else:
            self.sendLine("ack: " + line)

def main(reactor):
    certData = getModule(__name__).filePath.sibling('servercert.pem').getContent()
    cert = ssl.PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(certData)
    factory = protocol.Factory.forProtocol(TLSServer)
    factory.options = cert.options()
    endpoint = endpoints.TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8000)
    endpoint.listen(factory)
    return defer.Deferred()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import starttls_server
    task.react(starttls_server.main)
```

And the servercert.pem looks like:

```
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(PEM BITS SNIPPED FOR BREVITY AND PRIVACY/SECURITY!)
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
(PEM BITS SNIPPED FOR BREVITY AND PRIVACY/SECURITY!)
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

For the client side (running on the same machine curently), I've created clientcert.pem - which is basically just the certificate section of servercert.pem above. But this fails:

```
# openssl s_client -connect localhost:8000 -starttls smtp -cert clientcert.pem
unable to load client certificate private key file
140310331250504:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

I've tried producing the public key from the cert and inserting it at the top of clientcert.pem - no difference. I'm rather confused as to why it is expecting a *private* key client side. My understanding of TLS is that the private key remains very much that - private to the server?

Can someone please advise where I am going wrong? Is it something server side - either the pem file or my server code? Or the content of my clientcert.pem?

Thank you :)

Comment: Hopefully that was not a production server cert? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I *think* what you're trying to do here is tell the client to trust your self-signed server certificate, by telling it explicitly about the server's certificate as a certificate authority.

A "client certificate" is not how you do that.  A client certificate is a *private key for the client* which is *validated by the server*.  Your server in this code sample is not configured to verify client certificates.

To tell the `openssl s_client` command-line tool to use `clientcert.pem` (which it would be more accurate to name `serverauthority.pem`) you would say `openssl s_client -CAfile clientcert.pem`).

Comment: Thanks @Glyph I think know what I'm trying to achieve better than I do! As I understand it from our systems here (an old perl based system being brought into the C21st!)...

We need the client to have a pvt key which is validated by the server. Looking at [link]https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/core/howto/ssl.html#client-authentication the client and server code BOTH seem to want to use the same files for auth and cert data - surely this is wrong? 

Can you please explain to a TLS newbie what SHOULD go in these source files? Do they even do what I want / think? Thanks again!

Comment: Describing how to set up your own certificate authority is a little bit beyond the scope of a stack overflow answer :).  Perhaps add a new question about how to do client authentication and I can answer that separately?

Comment: Hi @Glyph... Really appreciate your help. I think my problem is more to do with the twisted examples: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/core/howto/ssl.html#client-authentication - and what files (what should be in them) from our existing valid certs etc that we have here I should use and how. Also it looks to me like the twisted examples above are wrong - eg ssl_clientauth_[server/client].py both use public.pem and server.pem - surely this isn't right? If I put a new question that is more specific about getting the above examples working, is this a valid question for stackoverflow?